# PHP : Error in using same variable in insert query

Tags: php, sql

So i have a multiple `insert query` and i use `$pcr_no` multiple times but i doesn't let me save the data.

here's my code:

```
 $sql_pcr = "INSERT INTO `tbl_pcr` VALUES ('', $pcr_un, $pcr_incident_location, $pcr_inc_date, $res_id )";
    if ($con->query($sql_pcr) === TRUE) {
        $pcr_no = $con->insert_id;

        $sql_pcr_con = "INSERT INTO `tbl_pcr_doc` VALUES ('',$pcr_no, $pcr_doc_scene, $pcr_medic_con, $pcr_doc_time, $pcr_doc_name, $pcr_specialty, $pcr_employer, $pcr_license_no, 'Blan2k');";
        $sql_pcr_con .= "INSERT INTO `tbl_pcr_skin` VALUES ('',$pcr_no,$pcr_skin)"; 

if ($con->multi_query($sql_pcr_con) === TRUE) {
        echo "PCR CONTENT";
    } else {
        echo "<br>Error: " . $sql_pcr_con . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
```

as you can see i get the `$pcr_no` from the last `inserted id` then i want to save that to multiple tables but it won't save. I tried changing the `$pcr_no`  the 2nd multiple insert to random numbers to see if it will save and successfully saved the data. so then is it not possible to use the variable `$pcr_no`multiple times?.

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try? You can try separating the queries into two inserts instead of doing a multi_query. You could also be running into quoting issues. You don't mention if it's throwing an error.

Comment: You're not inserting the values of your variables but just strings. Maybe take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp that shows you examples of how to write your queries.

Comment: im sorry. but the $pcr_no is not the error but in the $pcr_skin. i forgot its a implode and i didn't put ' ' . im very sorry.  but thanks for the replies